# How can you identify If the Sabre GetReservationRS SOAP Response contains NDC content?

Tags: soap, sabre

Travelport use the ZK status, Amadeus has a tag, how does Sabre identify this content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To identify NDC in Sabre GetReservationRQ, the path ProductBase/ProductType will have the value "AIR_NDC" (from Sabre support desk)

```
<stl19:Segment sequence="1" id="10">
<stl19:Product sequence="1" id="10" IsPast="false">
    <or114:ProductBase>
        <or114:ProductType>AIR_NDC</or114:ProductType>
        <or114:VendorCode>QF</or114:VendorCode>
        <or114:StatusCode>HK</or114:StatusCode>
        <or114:StartPoint>SYD</or114:StartPoint>
        <or114:StartDateTime>2023-05-29T19:00:00</or114:StartDateTime>
        <or114:EndPoint>MEL</or114:EndPoint>
        <or114:EndDateTime>2023-05-29T20:35:00</or114:EndDateTime>
        <or114:Text>QF 487E 29MAY J SYDMEL HK1 </or114:Text>
        <or114:Text>/NDQF*4JO5YD</or114:Text>
        <or114:Text>/QF081HAH1AXA2</or114:Text>
    </or114:ProductBase>
    <or114:ProductDetails productType="AIR_NDC">
        <or114:ProductName type="AIR_NDC">AIR_NDC</or114:ProductName>
        <or114:Air>
            <or114:DepartureAirport>SYD</or114:DepartureAirport>
            <or114:ArrivalAirport>MEL</or114:ArrivalAirport>
            <or114:MarketingAirlineCode>QF</or114:MarketingAirlineCode>
            <or114:MarketingFlightNumber>487</or114:MarketingFlightNumber>
            <or114:Cabin code="Y" sabreCode="Y" name="ECONOMY" shortName="ECONOMY" lang="EN"/>
            <or114:AirlineRefId>QF*4JO5YD</or114:AirlineRefId>
            <or114:DepartureDateTime>2023-05-29T19:00:00</or114:DepartureDateTime>
            <or114:ArrivalDateTime>2023-05-29T20:35:00</or114:ArrivalDateTime>
            <or114:ClassOfService>E</or114:ClassOfService>
            <or114:ActionCode>HK</or114:ActionCode>
            <or114:NumberInParty>1</or114:NumberInParty>
        </or114:Air>
    </or114:ProductDetails>
</stl19:Product></stl19:Segment>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I didn't believe Travelport's "ZK" status was exclusive to NDC as to the best of my knowledge is was and perhaps may still be, used by TAS (Travelport Aggregated Shopping)/Direct Payment Carriers segments including AirAsia (AK) and FR (RyanAir). In relation to Sabre, while I could be wrong, I thought Sabre's getBooking API (Booking Management) only returned NDC in addition to legacy (ATPCO). In the "flights" array a "sourceType" is provided which includes values like ATPCO (GDS content) and NDC.

Comment: You are correct about ZK status, it is not exclusive to NDC. There is a DI(InvoiceRmk) line in format #TAS01#XXXXX/XXXXXXXXXXXXX/USD/NDC that is the correct identifier.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly, I can verify that in the GetReservationRS, "Product_Type" with the identifier "AIR_NDC" would be used.
Here is an illustration of a PNR with two SQ x NDC segments, GetReservationRS for segment # 2.

UAZFCL
1.1BEAR/PADDINGTON MR
1 SQ 278W 20OCT F ADLSIN HK1  1010  1510  /NDSQ*559ABC/SQ-559ABC

2 SQ 279M 26OCT Q SINADL HK1  2310  0825  /NDSQ*559ABC/SQ-559ABC
TKT/TIME LIMIT

```
        <stl19:Product sequence="2" id="34" IsPast="false">
        <or114:ProductBase>
            <or114:ProductType>AIR_NDC</or114:ProductType>
            <or114:VendorCode>SQ</or114:VendorCode>
            <or114:StatusCode>HK</or114:StatusCode>
            <or114:StartPoint>SIN</or114:StartPoint>
            <or114:StartDateTime>2023-10-26T23:10:00</or114:StartDateTime>
            <or114:EndPoint>ADL</or114:EndPoint>
            <or114:EndDateTime>2023-10-26T08:25:00</or114:EndDateTime>
            <or114:Text>SQ 279M 26OCT Q SINADL HK1 </or114:Text>
            <or114:Text>/NDSQ*559ABC</or114:Text>
            <or114:Text>/SQ-559ABC</or114:Text>
        </or114:ProductBase>
        <or114:ProductDetails productType="AIR_NDC">
            <or114:ProductName type="AIR_NDC">AIR_NDC</or114:ProductName>
            <or114:Air>
                <or114:DepartureAirport>SIN</or114:DepartureAirport>
                <or114:ArrivalAirport>ADL</or114:ArrivalAirport>
                <or114:MarketingAirlineCode>SQ</or114:MarketingAirlineCode>
                <or114:MarketingFlightNumber>279</or114:MarketingFlightNumber>
                <or114:Cabin code="Y" sabreCode="Y" name="ECONOMY" shortName="ECONOMY" lang="EN"/>
                <or114:AirlineRefId>SQ*559ABC</or114:AirlineRefId>
                <or114:DepartureDateTime>2023-10-26T23:10:00</or114:DepartureDateTime>
                <or114:ArrivalDateTime>2023-10-27T08:25:00</or114:ArrivalDateTime>
                <or114:ClassOfService>M</or114:ClassOfService>
                <or114:ActionCode>HK</or114:ActionCode>
                <or114:NumberInParty>1</or114:NumberInParty>
            </or114:Air>
        </or114:ProductDetails>
    </stl19:Product>
</stl19:Segment>
```

</stl19:Segments>